# Define which tests are run after build in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2012 has a new feature where it automatically runs your unit tests after every build.

I would like to use this feature, but I have a number of tests that should not be run after every build (long running performance tests, etc).

Is there a way to define which categories are run automatically?  Or some other way to define which test should be run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A colleague of mine wanted to know the answer to this question also.

He asked [Cathy Sullivan](https://twitter.com/cathysull) (A Microsoft Visual Studio Program manager) on Twitter [whether it was possible](https://twitter.com/DanTup/status/228924022270873601).

Cathy came back and said that **unfortunately, it's not possible**, however as part of the [same conversation](https://twitter.com/JoshuaWeber4/status/230057867300982784), [Joshua Weber](https://twitter.com/JoshuaWeber4) (another MS VS Program Manager) stated that Visual Studio's "Run Tests On Build" will honor any current filter you've applied within the search box.

[(Image grab of twitter conversation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIFKg.png)

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if it is possible to filter by test category on the search box?

Comment: If anyone is interested, this is how I am making this work: I couldn't find any way to filter by category.  The best I found was the FullName filter, which will filter for any string in the namespace, class, or method name.  I am adding the text "AutoRun" to the class name of all the tests I want to run continuously.  In the Test Explorer, I search for: FullName:"AutoRun".  Then the "Run Tests After Build" feature works perfect.

Comment: You can filter by category.  They're called "Traits"   For instance, if you want to run all tests marked with category "fast", type: "Trait:fast".  If you want to run all tests NOT marked with category "slow", type "-Trait:slow".  No quotes.

Answer (score 2):

After update 1, you can filter on categories in the search box using the trait filter. See this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160105065503/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1-using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer.aspx) for more info.